# eBay API AddFixedPriceItem call returns 'The category selected is not a leaf category' error

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am making a call to eBay `AddFixedPriceItem` and it is returning the following error

```
The category selected is not a leaf category.
```

I tried various categories and still got the same response. So far I can't see any support for this solution at different forums.

Is there anyone who can guide me why it is happening and how do we identify which is a leaf category.

I also have a function that calls to eBay `GetCategories` and it simply returns an array of `category_ids` and `names`.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a listing, you need to add it to a leaf category, not a meta category or other categories in the category tree.

Which category are you trying to add your listing to?

For example, you can't add an item to catID=1 (Collectibles/Collectables). It's not a leaf. You need to find a subcategory that has no children, for example catID=165362, which is Collectibles > Comics > Bronze Age (1970-83) > **Sports** .